# Identify rows for removal depending on rules applied to multiple columns

Tags: r, if-statement, lapply

I would like to remove rows from my dataframe if the contents across multiple columns do not match varying user criteria.

The following repex should cover the complexity of what I am trying to achieve.

```
install.packages("dplyr")
install.packages("purrr")

options(stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

# Create user criteria (UC) data.
UC <- data.frame(
  Series = 1:5, 
  Unit = c("cm","mm",NA,NA,"cm"),
  Month = c(NA,NA,"Jan",NA,"Feb"), 
  Height = c(3,NA,NA,3,1)
)

# Create range of scenarios (RS) but only consider two series initially.
set.seed(2)
num_series <- 2
RS <- data.frame(
  Series = sample(c(1:5), num_series, replace=TRUE),
  Unit = sample(c("cm","mm"), num_series, replace=TRUE),
  Month = sample(c("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr"), num_series, replace=TRUE), 
  Height = sample(c(1:3), num_series, replace=TRUE) 
)

# Identify applicable critera for matching (AC).
AC <- dplyr::filter(UC, UC$Series %in% unique(RS$Series)) 
AC <- AC[, !purrr::map_lgl(AC, ~all(is.na(.))), drop=FALSE]

# Combine the scenario data and the applicable criteria.
SC <- merge(x=RS, y=AC, by="Series", all.x=TRUE) 

# Function to identify rows for removal.
fn_remove_row <- function(cols, rm) {
  x <- paste0(cols,".x")
  y <- paste0(cols,".y")
  rm$remove <- ifelse(rm$remove == 0 & !is.na(rm[[y]]) & rm[[y]] != rm[[x]], 1, rm$remove)
  rm[[y]] <- NULL
  setnames(rm, eval(substitute(x)), unlist(cols))
}

# Identify columns to be considered for matching for the given scenarios.
cols <- as.list(gsub("\\.y","",grep("\\.y", names(SC), value=TRUE)))

# Final dataframe (with option to filter).
SC$remove <- 0 # Initial values.
df <- cbind(data.frame(lapply(cols, fn_remove_row, rm=SC)))
#df <- dplyr::filter(df, remove == 0)
```

Some explanations on my code:

• The UC dataframe provides some example rules that may or may not apply to specific columns depending on the series observed in the data.

• The RS dataframe creates different data scenarios that need to be catered for although I initially only consider two scenarios. The `num_series` parameter can be increased to provide more scenarios.

• The AC dataframe subsets the user criteria to only select the columns that apply to the observed scenarios.

• The SC dataframe combines the scenario data and the applicable criteria. Columns with rules to be applied will be identified with a `.x` suffix (the original data) and a `.y` suffix (the criteria).

• I have created a function to consider the required columns in turn and check if the values match. If they do not match then the row will be flagged with a “1” to indicate it is to be removed. If the criteria value is missing (NA) for a particular column then there is no need to make a match in that case. After making the check, the criteria column is removed and the original data column is renamed to remove the suffix.

• I use `lapply` to create a final dataframe (df) containing a column to be filtered. The filter is not currently applied as the flags are not being created correctly.

The input dataframes (created with seed=2) are:

```
> UC                                  > RS
  Series Unit Month   Height            Series Unit Month Height
     1    cm   <NA>      3                 1    mm   Apr     1
     2    mm   <NA>     NA                 4    cm   Apr     3
     3   <NA>   Jan     NA
     4   <NA>  <NA>      3
     5    cm    Feb      1
```

Since RS contains series 1 and 4, AC is created to also contain these series and only the columns that remain applicable:

```
> AC
  Series Unit Height
     1    cm     3
     4   <NA>    3
```

The merge combines RS and AC as desired and the `remove` flag is initialised:

```
> SC
  Series Unit.x Month Height.x Unit.y Height.y remove
     1     mm    Apr      1     cm       3       0
     4     cm    Apr      3    <NA>      3       0
```

In this case I want to flag series 1 for removal because `Unit.x` does not equal `Unit.y` but if they did match it would still be flagged because `Height.x` does not equal `Height.y`. The Month column does not come into the equation because there was no applicable criteria for these two series.

Series 4 would not be flagged because the Unit comparison is not applicable (`Unit.y` = `NA`) and the Height comparison gives a match.

In the end I want (before filtering):

```
> df
  Series Unit  Month Height remove
     1     mm    Apr     1     1
     4     cm    Apr     3     0
```

But what I am getting from the `lapply` is repeated columns despite no `return()` call and various unshown `cbind` attempts:

```
> df
  Series Unit Month Height.x Height.y remove Series.1 Unit.x Month.1 Height Unit.y remove.1
     1    mm   Apr      1      3        1       1       mm     Apr   ...
```

Is `lapply` the wrong function for looping through the applicable columns or can it be made to work? It feels to me like there is just a tiny crucial element missing.

A full solution test should use different seeds and increase `num_series`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some what different/vectorized approach to this problem. I have tried to read this thoroughly and understand and hopefully have understood what exactly you are trying to do.

```
x <- paste0(cols,".x")
y <- paste0(cols,".y")
SC$remove <- as.integer(rowSums(!is.na(SC[y]) & SC[x] != SC[y]) > 0)
SC[y] <- NULL
names(SC)[names(SC) %in% x] <- cols

SC
#  Series Unit Month Height remove
#1      1   mm   Apr      1      1
#2      4   cm   Apr      3      0
```

You can extend this to many columns and can wrap it in a function if needed.

Comment: Great solution #Ronak Shah, this does exactly what I wanted and very efficiently too!

Answer (score 1):

It appears this is a good time to use a `for-loop` rather than our trusty `lapply` friend:

```
# Function to identify rows for removal.
fn_remove_row <- function(col, rm) {
  x <- paste0(col,".x")
  y <- paste0(col,".y")
  rm$remove <- ifelse(rm$remove == 0 & !is.na(rm[[y]]) & rm[[y]] != rm[[x]], 1, rm$remove)
  rm[[y]] <- NULL
  setnames(rm, eval(substitute(x)), unlist(col))
  return(rm)
}

# Identify columns to be considered for matching for the given scenarios.
cols <- c(gsub("\\.y","",grep("\\.y", names(SC), value=TRUE)))

# Final dataframe (with option to filter).
SC$remove <- 0 # Initial values.
for (i in 1:length(cols)) {
  col <- cols[i]
  SC <- fn_remove_row(col, SC)
}
```